# Chrome extension submission does not have section on declaring remote code

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to submit a Chrome Extension to their public store. However, I keep hitting this prompt:

> A justification for remote code use is required. This can be entered on the Privacy practices tab.

When I go to the "Privacy" tab though, I only have the following sections - Single Purpose, Permission justification and Data usage. Per Google's docs, it seems like there should be a "Declare any remote code" section https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/cws-dashboard-privacy/ , but there's not.

Am I crazy or does anyone know where to find this?

Looked through numerous S/O posts and Google docs. I think Google may have changed their UI or I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: v3 doesn't support remote code and Google stopped accepting v2 extensions back in January, 2022. (Preexisting v2 extensions are unlisted and are planned for removal in January 2024.) Not sure why you're getting that prompt at all.

Answer (score 0):

I quit Chrome, reopened my application and the section was then available. For what it's worth, it looks like someone else had this same issue https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/nn7NhHbqgIw